# (pl/sql) sysdate functions updates fields without time part

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sysdate

When I try:

```
UPDATE table_name SET modification_ts = SYSDATE WHERE id = ...
(modification_ts is Date type)
```

it updates the field without time part, eg: '27/11/2015'

When I write:

```
v_modification_ts DATE := SYSDATE;
UPDATE table_name SET modification_ts = v_modification_ts WHERE id = ...
```

it updates field to '27/11/2015 20:38:45'

What should I do to update with time using Sysdate() directly?

Comment: I don't think that is accurate.  SYSDATE function contains both date and time, so how are you viewing the results?  Please show COMPLETE example with table column definitions and types, and select statement to view the results.  What does "select to_char(modification_ts, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from table_name" show?

Comment: It's probably the way you _display_ the value. `sysdate` always behaves the same way regardless if you use it in SQL or PL/SQL

Comment: The oracle display settings regarding date and time functions (on client connections) is driven by the NLS configurations. Read about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76966/ch2.htm